# PHP Error, Undefined index error

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my codeigniter project I have this function in my model

```
function get_rtc_info($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('rtc_info', array('id' => $id));
        $query = $query->row_array();   
        $query = $query['id'].', '.$query['name'].', '.$query['address'];  //line# 313 
        return $query;
    }
```

I get the following error/warning when running the code

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: id , name and address
>   Filename: models/form_model.php
>   line number 313

I am not sure why I get this undefined index warnings. Can someone guide me on this error and how to resolve it. Thank you in advance

Comment: After `$quary=$quary->row_array();` put `die(var_dump($quary));` to see what items it contains.

Comment: You're probably calling that function with an `$id` that doesn't exist in the database, or your query is wrong. I'm not familiar with Codeigniter but you should find a way to check if the query returns results. If there no result, don't try to use them.

Comment: Check you $quary before concate , `print_r($quary)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! @ castis The result of die(var_dump($quary)); is `array(0) { }` . @caCtus23 I have the fields in the database, probably my query may be wrong, but It was working some hours ago.

Comment: @BeingSunny I get this message when using print_r($quary) `CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #35 [result_id] => Resource id #47 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [row_data] => ) `

Comment: it is codeigniter 2 @RejoanulAlam

Comment: @karma Is there are any rows available in your table `rtc_info`? table with no data/row show this kind of notice

Comment: @RejoanulAlam. As of now I just have 4 rows populated in the database table and all of them has data in every field.

Comment: There are lots of question with `Undefined index`. I think you did not searched any.Even the error message is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no rows in your table `rtc_info`. This is why you are watching this kind of notice. If you want, not show this notice check your variable with `isset()` before using

```
function get_rtc_info($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('rtc_info',array('id' => $id));
    $query = $query->row_array(); 

    if(isset($query['id']) && isset($query['name']) && isset($query['address'])) {
     $query = $query['id'].', '.$query['name'].', '.$query['address'];  //line# 313 
     return $query;
}else{
   return 'no data';
  }
}
```

if these 3 fields are optional you may use following without else block

```
function get_rtc_info($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('rtc_info',array('id' => $id));
    $query = $query->row_array(); 

    if(isset($query['id'])){
        $row_id = $query['id'];
     }else{
        $row_id = 'no id';
     }

     if(isset($query['name'])){
        $name = $query['name'];
     }else{
        $name = 'no name';
     }

     if(isset($query['address'])){
        $address= $query['address'];
     }else{
        $address = 'no address';
     }

     $query = $row_id.', '.$name.', '.$address;  //line# 313 
     return $query;
}
```

hope now clear

Comment: I added ur code snippet in my project, it works but the else block gets executed. Maybe the mistake is with my quary, since my database table has rows of data in it.

Comment: else block will be executed  until your table contains no rows(and all 3 filed must have data `id`, `name`, `address`)

Comment: Thanks now the problem is solved, there was no data in the other table not the rtc table. Thank you for the help. Appreciate it!

Comment: @karma answer more explained, see now. If still confusing let me know